# Can't boot from encrypted disk after deleting swap-memory partition [issue]

Tags: boot, luks, disk-encryption

I can't login anymore into my encrypted disk. After writing the password:

```
error: no such cryptodisk found.
error: disk ‘cryptouuid/HEXstring’ not found.
Entering rescue mode…
```

intuitively that string is the identifier of the disk that I'm trying to decrypt and log into.

So I live boot from USB and go into file manager, mount the encrypted disk and I can access it, since I know the correct password.

My resources are a live USB and every file I want from my encrypted disk, since I actually can enter into the partition.

History of what I've done before rebooting and finding this problem:

- masked the swap unit
- deleted the partition where the swap unit was

How can I fix the system not recognising my cryptodisk during boot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to do something alone (yes, I'm the answerer to my own question. I was panicking) and I did this in order to re-access my account:

- after I ran the live USB, I mounted my linux partition so that I could access to its files. I personally did it from the file manager but you can use the `mount` function.
- with the `sudo` command I opened /etc/default/grub with a text editor
- uncommented the voice "GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK=y"
  It will allow the system to boot from an encrypted disk, where the grub file configuration is located.

I'm not an expert neither in Linux systems neither in programming, so I don't know if this was a good method. Anyways I thought about this because I found, in /boot/grub/grub.cfg :

```
`if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
```

`search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root`
`--hint='cryptouuid/HEX_string_of_my_encrypted_disk'`

`else`

`search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root HEX_string_of_the_swap_partition`

So I thought it was selecting, as the bootloader disk, the swap partition of my cryptodisk instead of the actual cryptodisk and that's why I searched for the option above written and un-commented it.

Right now the system runs ok, but at the beginning a message has been sent through the screen, which was something like:

```
hibernation device not found
```

or something very similar. Which I guess it's just expected since I have no swap memory anymore.

So, this is ONE solution, again, not sure if the best.